# A strange feature in Ubuntu document viewer

Tags: 14.04, pdf, evince

While browsing through a tutorial lecture pdf using the default Document Viewer in Ubuntu, I noticed a strange feature. When I select the text, below it there is some overlapping text (totally different from the text visible in the document). Can you explain what this text actually is, and how can it be extracted separately? Additional info: I think the pdf was created using a word file(mentioned in the properties). Attached photos:

- text selected: [image]
- without selection: [image]

File: [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz7QVPFEX9ZYWUx5Y0k1MmpLbzQ)
Note: A similar feature can be observed in any pdf which contains mathematical symbols too, though in that case, the symbols don't make any sense, which makes it useless.

Comment: One thing to try is to press Ctrl+A to select all, press Ctrl+C to copy, open Gedit or some other text editor, and press Ctrl+V to paste.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex It is not understandable that way (the mingled text appears in between), plus it doesn't explain where the text came from.